# How to define alias for PerRequestLifetimeManager, getting "could not be resolved" error

Tags: unity-container

I'm trying to define an alias for PerRequestLifetimeManager, and use it in the container configuration section,  but I keep getting this error: "The type name or alias PerRequestLifetimeManager could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name."  What am I missing?    The other 2 aliases work fine, but they are not in the same dll...

```
      <!-- not working -->
      <typeAlias alias="request" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.PerRequestLifetimeManager ,          Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc"/>

      <!-- working -->
      <typeAlias alias="singleton" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager,                      Microsoft.Practices.Unity"/>
      <typeAlias alias="external" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager,                      Microsoft.Practices.Unity"/>
```

**UPDATE**

Below is my unity config section.  I get a "The type name or alias request could not be resolved." error.

```
 <unity>
    <typeAliases>
      <!-- Lifetime manager types -->
      <typeAlias alias="singleton" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager,                      Microsoft.Practices.Unity"/>
      <typeAlias alias="external" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager,                      Microsoft.Practices.Unity"/>
      <typeAlias alias="request" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.PerRequestLifetimeManager ,          Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc"/>
   </typeAliases>
    <containers>
      <container name="main">
        <types>
          <type type="IProvider" mapTo="ConcreteProvider">
            <lifetime type="request"/>
          </type>
        </types>
    </container>
     </containers>
</unity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put some very simple sample together and the below setup works for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration
   .UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="ILogger" type="ConsoleApplication2.ILogger, ConsoleApplication2" />
    <alias alias="request" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.PerRequestLifetimeManager,
     Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc" />
    <container name="MyContainer">
      <register type="ILogger" mapTo="ConsoleApplication2.FileLogger,
     ConsoleApplication2" />
    </container>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE 6/8/2014 for the comments below.**

A. Create a new project i. C# Console App .NET v 4.5
B. Install-Package Unity
C. Install-Package Unity.Mvc

Package.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Unity" version="3.5.1404.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Unity.Mvc" version="3.5.1404.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0.5" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Use the configuration file.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            container.LoadConfiguration("MyContainer");
            var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public interface ILogger
    {
    }

    public class FileLogger : ILogger
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a full unity config section example.  Unity can't seem to find PerRequestLifetimeManager.  I have it referenced in the project & I updated the project to 4.5.  Singleton works fine.

Comment: Did you install the Unity.Mvc from Nuget packages? I also have the latest version of Unity installed.

Comment: yes, I installed from nuget.  I can see PerRequestLifetimeManager in my sites object browser

Comment: did you have to add any code related to PerRequestLifetimeManager  to get it to work?

Comment: thanks that was a big help.  2 issues though.  1) You need to add <lifetime type="request"/> under the <container><types><type> element to use request.  I believe unity defaults to transient otherwise.  2) I added all  this to an MVC project because per request needs to be used on a web project.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Spock. Based on your answer and comment I was able to complete the implementation. I was trying to register my *DbContext* in configuration file and select the *LifetimeManager = PerRequestLifetimeManager*. The namespaces of the Unity package has changed in the latest nuget package.

- Unity v5.8.6
- Unity.Mvc v5.0.13

Here's how my config file looks like

```
 <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection,  Unity.Configuration" />

<alias alias="PerRequest" type="Unity.AspNet.Mvc.PerRequestLifetimeManager, Unity.Mvc" />
```

And inside the container, here's how I'm registering my dbcontext

```
<register  type ="MyNameSpace.DbEntities, AssemblyName" mapTo="MyNameSpace.DbEntities, AssemblyName">
      <lifetime type="PerRequest"/>
</register>
```

Thank you.